# Delete Printer with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, printing, attributes

First if all my coding knowledge is very basic.

We have a company printer which users should use but since a lot of them are working from home, they are using the printers they have at home.

I don't want users to use other printers so created a GPO to hide printer settings. Even though this works fine, users can still print on the already added printers.

I'm trying to use PowerShell to delete printers. What I have so far is: `wmic printer where "NOT deviceid like '%PrinterName%'" delete`. This should delete all printers where the printer name is NOT LIKE `PrinterName` and it does, but I don't want some printers like **Microsoft XPS Document Writer** or **Snagit** to be deleted.

How can I define a list of exceptions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tricky to figure out which printers you need to exclude from deletion... What about OneNote, Fax, Microsoft XPS Document Writer, Microsoft Print to PDF and people could have labelprinters at home like a Dymo.. Delete those too?

Comment: As I mentioned above, i dont want "Print to PDF" and "OneNote" or "Snagit" to be deleted. I want do define which printers can stay.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I didn't execute this myself, but you can exclude printers from the list of installed printers and remove the rest like below:

```
# determine the list of printers that should NOT be deleted
# this is a regex string where the matched parts are combined with a pipe symbol (regex 'OR')
$excludes = 'Print to PDF|OneNote|Snagit|Fax|XPS Document'

# get the printer names currently installed, excluding the printers in $excludes
(Get-Printer).Name -notmatch $excludes | ForEach-Object {
    # delete the remaining printers
    wmic printer where Name="$_" delete
}
```

Of course, the main thing here is that you define what should be deleted and what should stay very carefully.. As commented, do you allow for people to conect a labelprinter like Dymo, Brother, Brady and what have-you or should devices like that also be removed?
You could end up having angry users like this..

Comment: Yes, all printers not allowed also labelprinters should be removed, when i execute the PS i get an error even if idefined printers i want to keep.




wmic : ERROR:
At line:8 char:5
+     wmic printer where DeviceID="$_" delete
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Description = Invalid query

Comment: @JanHansen I changed from `DeviceID` to `Name` in the wmic command. Can you check please?

Comment: Hi Theo 
I got the same error: _
wmic : FEHLER:
In Zeile:8 Zeichen:5
+     wmic printer where Name="$_" delete
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (FEHLER::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
wmic : FEHLER:
In Zeile:8 Zeichen:5
+     wmic printer where Name="$_" delete
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (FEHLER::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Beschreibung = Die Anfrage ist ungltig._

Comment: Anyone else an idea?